# Why doesn't this really simple CSS work?

Tags: css

The .hide class is dynamically applied and removed. No matter what I do, I simply cannot get this div to animate when it shows.

```
div{
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hide{
    transform: scaleY(0);
}
```

Comment: Please supply enough code to reproduce the problem. The code you've included works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/8baxw341/

Comment: Some HTML would be nice. (I'm assuming that's where your problem lies.)

Comment: I've prepared example https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/s5hsf7rs/ (you can toggle class "hide" by clicking on div) and everithing works fine

Comment: It's probably something to do with Vue. The hide class is bound to a computed variable, and triggered from a button press in another component. Perhaps standard CSS transitions just don't work in Vue.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/fw0mr58k/

```
transform: scaleY(0);
```

Here is an example of your code with some javascript events 
If it's not working, codnisder using vendor prefixes, because it can depend on browser.

Also, You might have some conflicts with parent elements. Please provide full code sample